# How to get Json response in Array using postman tool ,is that possible?, if yes, please solution

Tags: arrays, json, api, arraylist, postman

when I hit the API and after this, I got the response in JSON format while using the Postman tool, 
I want all of that response come in array
is that possible?
if, yes, please tag the solution

Comment: What's the API, What does the response look like? Do you want the actual response to change or to save the response as a new array somewhere?

Comment: http://sheeda.consoliads.com/sheeda/admin/api_v1/startNewAdSession_2

Comment: I want the JSON response in an array , simply

Comment: actually, I want to automate the API response